# Custom message on wait timeout error

Tags: testing, selenium, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

From time to time I'm using ["Expected Conditions" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor) introduced in protractor 1.7.

**Use case**:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(header.displayName), 10000);
```

where `header` is a Page Object.

If `header.displayName` would not become visible in 10 seconds, an error would be thrown:

```
[firefox #4]   2) Describe description here
[firefox #4]    Message:
[firefox #4]      Error: Wait timed out after 10082ms
[firefox #4]    Stacktrace:
[firefox #4]      Error: Wait timed out after 10082ms
[firefox #4] ==== async task ====
[firefox #4]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Path/to/project/test/e2e/my.spec.js:38:17)
```

Which is not quite readable and require some time to understand and a bit of a research.

**Question:**

Is it possible to customize this kind of a wait timeout error?

---

FYI, we can provide custom `expect` failure messages as described here:

- [Print message on expect() assert failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251887/print-message-on-expect-assert-failure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `browser.wait()` takes 3 parameters: a condition, an optional timeout, and an optional description message.  (I'm pretty sure this is the doc: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait, but I'm having a hard time verifying that the WebDriver shows up as `browser` in protractor).  So you should be able to do:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var timeoutMS = 10 * 1000;
var timeoutMsg = "Waiting for header displayName";
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(header.displayName), timeoutMS, timeoutMsg);
```

Comment: That was it, cannot believe it is built-in, pretty handy. Thanks again!