# Protractor expected condition for element containing any text

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

Is there a way how to check whether an element has any text in it? I already found `textToBePresentInElement` but this function checks for specified value and does not return a proper error if it fails.

I'm population the element via API and it's loaded bit later, so I want the browser to wait till any information appears in the element and then check for correct value.

Alternatively it would be also very helpful to manage to get a specific error message when EC fails:

```
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.binding('myvar')), "expected"), 5000);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The third argument to `browser.wait()` is a custom error message:

```
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.binding('myvar')), "expected"), 5000, "Text is not something I've expected");
```

See also:

- [Custom message on wait timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979368/custom-message-on-wait-timeout-error)

---

To wait for an element to contain any text, you can write a *custom expected condition*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var anyTextToBePresentInElement = function(elementFinder) {
  var hasText = function() {
    return elementFinder.getText().then(function(actualText) {
      return actualText;
    });
  };
  return EC.and(EC.presenceOf(elementFinder), hasText);
};
```

And here is the usage:

```
browser.wait(anyTextToBePresentInElement(element(by.binding('myvar'))), 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. It's pretty perfect with third argument for `browser.wait()` function. Unfortunately I'm not able to run custom expected condition. It says "undefined function". Is there any documentation for custom expected conditions?

Comment: @abimelex oops, my mistake, I've updated the answer, check it out. Thanks.

Comment: It's a while ago, but I guess it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

The previous code snippet works form but with a small update: `return actualText;` should be boolean. So the whole code will be:

```
var anyTextToBePresentInElement = function(elementFinder) {
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  var hasText = function() {
    return elementFinder.getText().then(function(actualText) {
      return !!actualText;
    });
  };
  return EC.and(EC.presenceOf(elementFinder), hasText);
};
```

Usage example:

```
var el = element(by.binding('myvar'));
browser.wait(anyTextToBePresentInElement(el, 5000, 'Element still has no text');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one

```
        export function titleType(textReference, expectedText)
        {
            textReference.then(function(name)
            {
                if (name == expectedText)
                {
                    expect(textReference).toContain(expectedText);
                    expect(name).toEqual(expectedText);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new TypeError("Wrong " + expectedText + "  name " + name);
                }
            });
        }
```