# How to handle errors/exceptions occurred in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

i am trying to make my script so robust so that if there is any error in my logic or on page, I want to notification with user defined message instead of that red color error messages like element on found or find Element().... is not a function.
I implemented code [image: Suggested]

But it is not working.

i also tried with code mentioned on [image: Suggested] 
But it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chai` library for assertions.

See the documentation, eg. for `equal`:

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal

You can set custom message like as a second parameter:

`expect('foo').to.equal('bar', 'Test failed with custom message');`

Comment: Hi @Kacper,  
Thank you for your quick response, however we are using jasmine in our project and we need to implement in jasmine only, please suggest

Comment: In Jasmine it looks pretty the same. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24980483/6331748

Comment: Hi @Kacper, Thanks again for your suggestion, i reviewed the information provided on above mentioned link.

Comment: I reviewed the information provided on above mentioned link. and i observed that that logic is  implemented with expect only and if my expect is not true then only that message will be printed. But i guess exception like
 "**get Text() not a function**"  or 
"**Element Not Visible Error**" or 
"**staled element**" for any web element on page. 
How can we get such exception using code?

Comment: Hi i tried with displaying with custom message way but it is not working can you please look and let me know what am i doing wrong. below is the code i tried with the output

Comment: var calcObj = require('../PageElements/CalcPageobject');
var noExceptionOccur = true
describe('Test Calculation initial opertaion', function () {
  it('Test first time', async function () {
    calcObj.appUrl();
    calcObj.firstField().sendKeys('12')
    calcObj.secondField().sendKeys('12');
    calcObj.goClick();
    var final = calcObj.finalResult();
    expect(final).toEqual('25', 'Result is not correct');
  });
});

Comment: Output: 1) Test Calculation initial opertaion Test first time
  - Expected '24' to equal '25'.

Comment: expect(final).toEqual('21',"This the reason of fail");               This is not working for me