# How to configure jasmine to logout message when expect was failed

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

I have a Jasmine check point to check the expect error message, and when the check point was failed, I only get the following message:

> Error: Failed expectation

Question is, is there any configuration to let jasmine output the actual message?

`expect(messageInfo).toContain("unauthorized");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print message on expect() assert failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251887/print-message-on-expect-assert-failure)

Comment: There are two ways, if you're on protractor 6 then look for `.withContext()`, else second argument after the matcher